# How to execute PHP on Specific HTML Files on NGINX

Tags: php, html, nginx

I'm executing PHP code inside some my HTML files, but since I only want to do this on certain files, I want to create `.htaccess` rules for specific files only.

My current config works fine but it all my html files, even static ones interpreted through PHP engine;

```
    # handle .php
    location ~ \.(php|html|htm)$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        include      nginxconfig.io/php_fastcgi.conf;
    }
```

What I tried to far is on `.htaccess` file but looks like it only works with Apache;

```
<Files mypage.html>
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html 
</Files>
```

Should I create `location` for each html file I should want to work with PHP?

Comment: Any specific reason why these files don't have the `.php` extension since they contain PHP?

Comment: Because of the possibilities to change technologies later, while keeping the static part easily. Also this; http://www.w3.org/TR/cooluris/ :)

Comment: Sounds like early optimization to me. What do you figure would be gained by this? If you swap out PHP for something else, wouldn't you still need to change the rules where `php` is hardcoded anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use exact matching:

```
    # add another location:
    location = /mypage.html {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        include      nginxconfig.io/php_fastcgi.conf;
    }
```

Comment: It looks like, exact matching seems to be a better option, is there any useful way to apply single matching rule for several files? For instance I want to apply it for `mypage.html` and `yourpage.html`. Or should I create a block for each of them?

Comment: If they are just a handful in number just create one location for each.

Comment: Thank you Danila, it feels great to see someone interested in even tiny bit of performance tweaks :) I started to use `location ~ /api/?.*\.(php|html|htm)$`